# Google sheets - copy data from rows to columns with column value condition

Tags: google-sheets, transpose

I have a sheet where I am getting payment data from customers with date, name and amount. This is transactional data and more rows keep coming to it.

I need to copy that data to a different sheet in columns so that all payments for each customer come in front for their name and all payments in one month appear in total monthly payment.

This sample sheet has the input data sheets of Product and Services and Target is something I need to prepare automatically for all new entries in frist 2 sheets.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YInJUkCw0TaegYKHVw6JGHKIZ9Wz6xYiOrhcIW2ya64

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Kokab, I suggest to compile with that formula

```
={"Product/services","Receipt No","Date","customer number","Name","Code","Payment";
QUERY({
ARRAYFORMULA({IF(ISBLANK(Product!A2:A),,"Product") ,Product!A2:F});
ARRAYFORMULA({IF(ISBLANK(Services!A2:A),,"Services") ,Services!A2:F})
},"select * where Col1 <> '' order by Col2")}
```

then perform a pivot table as following https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19dj_A1pYm5pLqb_S69EdBfn_C3K43CanL7qPDuZLDY8/edit?usp=sharing